# Why my variable value changes by itself randomly?

Tags: c, hashtable, access-violation

I'm a newbie to C programming and I start learning data structures and algorithms just recently. The textbook I select is *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C*, which introduces the hash table ADT in Chap.5. And here is one implementation of its quad open addressing version, in which the function **Find** passes values of *Key* and *TableSize* to **Hash** function and it will return the hashed value as the variable *CurrentPos*. The following are function **Hash** and **Find**:

```
Index
Hash( ElementType Key, int TableSize )
{
    return Key % TableSize;
}

Position
Find(ElementType Key, HashTable H)
{
    Position CurrentPos;
    int CollisionNum;

    CollisionNum = 0;
    CurrentPos = Hash(Key, H->TableSize);
    while(H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Info != Empty && H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element != Key)
    {
        CurrentPos += 2 * ++CollisionNum - 1;
        if(CurrentPos >= H->TableSize)
            CurrentPos -= H->TableSize;
    }
    return CurrentPos;
}
```

And here is the header:

```
    typedef int ElementType;
    #ifndef _HashQuad_H
    #define _HashQuad_H

    typedef unsigned int Index;
    typedef Index Position;

    struct HashTbl;
    typedef struct HashTbl *HashTable;

    HashTable InitializeTable( int TableSize );
    void DestroyTable( HashTable H );
    Position Find( ElementType Key, HashTable H );
    void Insert( ElementType Key, HashTable H );
    ElementType Retrieve( Position P, HashTable H );
    HashTable Rehash( HashTable H );

    #endif
```

And the following are typedefs and structs in source file:

```
    struct HashEntry
    {
        ElementType      Element;
        enum KindOfEntry Info;
    };

    typedef struct HashEntry Cell;

    /* Cell *TheCells will be an array of */
    /* HashEntry cells, allocated later */
    struct HashTbl
    {
        int TableSize;
        Cell *TheCells;
    };
```

This is the way H being initialized

```
    HashTable
    InitializeTable( int TableSize )
    {
        HashTable H;
        int i;

    if( TableSize < MinTableSize )
        {
            Error( "Table size too small" );
            return NULL;
        }

        /* Allocate table */
        H = malloc( sizeof( struct HashTbl ) );
        if( H == NULL )
            FatalError( "Out of space!!!" );

        H->TableSize = NextPrime( TableSize );

        /* Allocate array of Cells */
        H->TheCells = malloc( sizeof( Cell ) * H->TableSize );
        if( H->TheCells == NULL )
            FatalError( "Out of space!!!" );

        for( i = 0; i < H->TableSize; i++ )
            H->TheCells[ i ].Info = Empty;

        return H;
    }
```

Now the problem is, however this implementation works fine for most cases. It does encounter crash sometimes. When it happens, I try unit-test and find that after calling of **Hash** function at one certain round, the value of *CurrentPos* will be assigned to be a integer that's much larger than the actual return value of **Hash** function, it could be 1000 plus or even bigger.
For example, if *Key* is 29918 and *TableSize* is 101, the correct answer and yes the returned value by **Hash** is 22, but after the assignment line:

```
 CurrentPos = Hash(Key, H->TableSize);
```

The value of *CurrentPos* changes to be 1580 all by itself, for no reason.
Note that the *Key* value at the time that's randomly assigned using **rand()** based on a seed of function **time()** is less than the upper-boundary of type integer - I mean there should be no overflow.

I tried hard to look closer to the Watches, but there is no other error or clue. I'm confused because this error happens really randomly. Is there anyone who's familiar with this?

Comment: Without knowing how `H` is initialized, what `H->TableSize` contains, whether the `TheCells` info is correct, it's hard to guess. Also, do you mean that `CurrentPos` is unexpectedly large *immediately* on return from the `Hash()` function, or that a larger-than-expected value is returned by `Find()`? If the latter, is it still less than `H->TableSize`?

Comment: arm... wouldnt the key words index and position cause syntax error in plain C? Or in whcih way they are behaving?

Comment: If you are mismanaging memory and storing a pointer to improper memory (for example, a pointer to what was once a local variable), then the values at the end of the pointer can change 'spontaneously' when the memory is reused.

Comment: @true: yes, but the typedefs for Position and Index (and ElementType and HashTable and maybe others) are not shown.

Comment: Please study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same idea.  The problem isn't self-evidently in the code you show.  The chances are, therefore, that it is in the code that you don't show.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your suggestion, this is my 1st post on  StackOverFlow and thus I really don't know all the rules. Now I'm editing my question to show all that's needed.

Comment: Thanks.  You're learning; that's all we ask — we don't expect perfection the first time around (though it's always good). Please note the 'Minimal' and 'Short' parts of the titles.  It isn't an invitation to dump all of a 300 line (or bigger) program into the question.

Comment: Hint: start by using **unsigned** types for all indexes; especially currentpos , tablesize and collisionnum. And put an assert inside the loop. BTW: IIUC your 2*n -1 increment may generate short cycles for some values of tablesize.

Comment: @joop Thanks for your help, i think i do use unsigned int for all the indexes. And for assert macros, i'm still learning and for the time being i only know how to use built-in debugging tools in VS. And if this is not too bothering, can you explain the short cycles generated by my increment a little bit? Thx

Comment: @PaulRoub Thank you Paul, now I've posted all the codes relevant as I think. And the *CurrentPos* is IMMEDIATELY unexpectedly large.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank u again, u mentioned "mismanaging" and "storing a pointer to improper memory". And I wonder how this happens, cause I always think the allocation of memory for a pointer is finished automatically by complier. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: The standard way to achieve it is `char *function(void) { char x[] = "like this!"; return x; }`, returning a pointer to a local variable.  There are other ways to do it too: `char *function(void) { char *x = malloc(sizeof("like this!")); free(x); return x; }`.  Usually, it won't be quite as blatant as in these examples, but the net result is much the same.  And no, the C compiler assumes you are an expert -- it doesn't warn you if you do something dubious.  Well, not by default. If you're using `gcc`, I recommend compiling with `-Wall` as a minimum; I use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and some more.

Answer (score 2):

If `CollisionNum` becomes sufficiently large then this test will not work correctly:

```
       if(CurrentPos >= H->TableSize)
            CurrentPos -= H->TableSize;
```

since if `CurrentPos >= H->TableSize*2` then `CurrentPos` will still be out of range after the subtraction of `H->TableSize`.

You should change this to either:

```
       while (CurrentPos >= H->TableSize)
            CurrentPos -= H->TableSize;
```

or:

```
       CurrentPos = CurrentPos % H->TableSize;
```

or even:

```
       CurrentPos %= H->TableSize;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Paul. But I don't think this is the problem, because when this happens, error message comes as Access Violation, which I think it means the value of *CurrentPos* is larger than the length of TheCells[], so TheCells[*CurrentPos*] is illegal

Comment: You should make this change regardless - it's just good defensive programming, even if you think it can "never happen".

Comment: Thank you Pual, I got it and will make my code more defensive. There's a lot of stuff I lack as a newbie. Thanks for your experience.